# Does WPML translate numbers automatically, or do I have to do the string translation?

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml, xgettext

I'm developing my site in **English**, and when I'm done, I'll be turning it into Arabic. I'm using a function and wondering whether I should wrap it into a gettext call for WPML to get or just leave it as it is and it will be converted into **Arabic** automatically (since it's numbers and not text)?

Should I do this?

```
<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;?>
```

Or keep it like this?

```
<?php echo sprintf(__('%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count));?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is better to use gettext calls, according to WPML Guidelines.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Can never go wrong with following the guidelines.